# Lumix G7: Raw photos only in 1920x1440, no higher res available

Tags: raw, camera-settings, resolution, panasonic, specification

On a G7 I bought used the images come with a 4592x3448 resolution for JPEG and 1920x1440 for raw. When I switch the mode to RAW only, the resolution/image size option in the menu is greyed out.

Is there some other setting I am unware of that makes higher res unavailable?

Or could it be caused by a buggy (custom) firmware the previous owner might have installed?

I can't believe the higher res is only available for JPEG by design -- can anybody familiar with Lumix cameras confirm this?
I can't really find the statement that RAW in full resolution is available explicitly in the specs:  https://shop.panasonic.com/cameras-and-camcorders/cameras/lumix-interchangeable-lens-ilc-cameras/DMC-G7HK.html#pnsb2c-pdp-specifications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry — the RAW files are the full resolution. They contain all of the data recorded by the camera. The option to change resolution is grayed out because there's no in-camera way to reduce it, not because it is stuck on small.

However, for that data to be *viewed*, it need to be interpreted. See [What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271/1943) for more on this. Because of this, RAW files also include an embedded JPEG preview. This lets you quickly see the camera's rendering of the image on an image viewer or operating system file preview window.

My guess is that on your camera, this embedded preview is lower resolution. Open your RAW file in a RAW processing program like Rawtherapee, Darktable, or Lightroom, and you'll get full resolution.

Comment: Thanks! So it WAS a pitfall, just not with the camera, but in my case the IrfanView plugin. I never would have guessed this was the issue here. Thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

What you see is likely not the RAW image, but the JPEG thumbnail/preview that is included in the RAW, which is what you usual picture viewer is going to find and display.

To see the RAW at full size, you have to open it with a proper application. The camera normally comes with a CD/DVD to install such apps (SilkyPix, for Lumix cameras), or it can be downloaded from the manufacturer's site.

Generic apps are also possible (Lightroom, RawTherapee, DarkTable...), but check that they support your camera.

Comment: Both Rawtherapee and Darktable support this camera. I assume Lightroom does as well.

Comment: The G7 should include a version of Silkypix on the CD. Though maybe easier to use RawTherapee anyway.

Comment: A long time ago I had a Lumix Z8 and was not very impressed with SIlkyPix anyway.