# Edit RAW DNG data without demosaic

Tags: raw, software, dng

Is there any software to edit RAW DNG pixel data without demosaic, and save changes directly to RAW?

Comment: Keep in mind that whatever you see on your monitor, whether demosaiced or not, has also had a lot of other processing applied to make it a viewable image. For  more, please see: [What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271/15871) and [Why RAW and JPEG look the same?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/112628/15871) You might think what you are looking at on your screen is "THE raw file" but what you are seeing is a very processed version of monochromatic luminance values for each photosite/sensel/pixel well.

Comment: For more on how colors are created from monochromatic luminance values, please see: [RAW files store 3 colors per pixel, or only one?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/86170/15871) and [Why are Red, Green, and Blue the primary colors of light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99706/15871) The latter goes into great detail about how the way we process raw files mimics the way our brains *create* color information from the simple brightness values sent to it by the cones in our retinas.

Comment: Another question for which the accepted answer describes the fundamental difference between a raw file with, say, 14-bit monochromatic luminance values and a TIFF file with 16-bit per 3 RGB color channels and the color multipliers *already baked in* is [Why can software correct white balance more accurately for RAW files than it can with JPEGs?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100925/15871)

Comment: Hi, I need to adjust the monochromatic luminance values of pixels, and save to RAW again. And then open in a "RAW processing software".

Comment: I'm not aware of any available product that does that. You would in effect be generating a new raw file, but nothing currently out there does that. What kind of adjustments do you wish to make? Why can't you use the raw processing software you plan to use afterwards to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The RAW data is the RAW data. You do not save changes to the raw file.

**I.E.** You can not alter the data within the RAW file/container itself.

If you use software to edit the RAW data you then save those edits to another file format such as JPEG or TIFF, the RAW file/container itself is not changed.

I do not know if there is any software that will **read** a RAW file without first applying demosaic. That is above my pay grade.

I would suggest you do some research on RAW files in books as well as on the internet so you have foundation of  knowledge of what one  needs to do to work with them. This will help you to ask informed questions.

Comment: RawTherapee, raw->Demosaicing->method->none

Comment: You're not even really "editing" the raw data. You're editing the instruction set used to process the raw data into a viewable image. Raw data is like a latent, undeveloped film negative. There's no way to see it without doing some development (which in the case of chemical photography is irreversible). In the case of raw image data, it can be converted with a near infinite number of different instruction sets without altering the original data.

Answer (score 1):

As user [Please Read My Profile](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/please-read-my-profile) demonstrates in his answer to [What does an unprocessed RAW file look like?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105271/15871), DCRaw and many of the raw conversion applications which draw upon DCRaw under their hoods are capable of doing what you desire in terms of converting linear sensor output to a viewable monochrome image without demosaicing.

With some raw processors that use DCRaw under the hood you can save the *instruction set* as a sidecar file or as an internal part of the raw image file, but you can't save the changes to the actual raw sensor output data in the file. The instructions would probably only be readable by the same application that created them, though. You can export what you see on your screen after doing the adjustments as a TIFF or in another raster image format, but you'll have the black point, white point and color multipliers more or less "baked in."

Even though the displayed and exported image is monochrome, the relative tonal values between pixels (in the image) that correspond to sensels/photo sites/pixel wells (on the sensor) filtered by red', green', and blue' filters¹, respectively, will be affected by the color temperature, white balance, and color filters that are applied to the raw luminance values.

<sub>¹ We call them *red'*, *green'*, and *blue'* filters, but they're actually not the same colors as the Red, Green, and Blue primary colors we use in RGB devices. The *red'* filters in most Bayer masks is centered somewhere around 590-600nm that is more of a yellow-orange color than "Red" at 640nm. Likewise, the *green'* and *blue'* filters are slightly different than their RGB counterparts. *Blue'* filters are a bit closer to violet than RGB "Blue" and *green'* filters are a little closer to yellow than RGB "Green" is.</sub>

For more about DCRaw, which runs on a Linux platform, please see the explanation and FAQs [here](https://www.dechifro.org/dcraw/).

<sub>Note that most cameras which were available by 2018 are supported, but newer cameras may not be supported at all and aren't fully supported unless they use the same sensor and raw encoding method as a previous model that was already around in 2018.</sub>

Comment: Didn't know about different colors of RGB filters. Where do I find out more about this?

Comment: @jsmith [Why are Red, Green, and Blue the primary colors of light?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99706/15871) and [Why don't mainstream sensors use CYM filters instead of RGB?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/43469/15871)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to adjust the monochromatic luminance values of pixels, and save to RAW again. And then open in a "RAW processing software

This is (basically) equivalent to making an adjustment to exposure in post processing in any RAW processing system.  You do not need to save and exit and reload to do that - it can all be done in one go.

Darktable (a free raw processing application I use myself) has an automatic setting for exposure that will do that without user intervention being required if you want.  There's the default "manual" setting as well, of course.  I'd expect other RAW processing applications to have similar options.

You do not save RAW data back and it would make little sense to do that - it would be like overwriting a negative - you want to keep the RAW data unaltered.  That's the point of RAW - to have the actual data recorded that you can always go back to without any processing applied.

Answer (score 0):

While theoretically possible, there is, to my knowledge, no existing software to do that; probably because there is little need for such an operation. If you have a specific need to do this, you'll have to write your own program. You can look into the DCRaw source code to read RAW files, you'll have to implement the writing yourself.

One application i know of that does (did) write to raw was the [Zero Noise Virtual Raw](http://www.guillermoluijk.com/article/virtualraw/index_en.htm) project by Guillermo Luijk where he combined multiple RAW exposures into one, as a HDR input. But there seems little use for that as modern RAW processors will handle multiple input files for HDR just fine these days.

Answer (score -1):

So no need to save as raw, you always have the raw file and any editing you do to it. But the other part of the question can partially be rephrased as "can I get the pure luminence values from the raw file?" This would seem to give you a b&w sensor without going to the expense of buying a pure mono camera. My understanding is rawtherapee has a "no demosaicing" option, which I'm guessing is just what the sensor itself sees. Am I correct?
Perhaps I can go on to answer my own question. Yes, and no. Yes it's what the sensor sees but no, on a mono camera each pixel sees the entire spectrum but on a colour camera a pixel sees one of red, green or blue segments only.